# Cannot boot up computer

Tags: boot, windows-7, 32-bit

I installed ubuntu and burned the iso file to the d drive. After I reboot my computer, the ubuntu install menu shows up. I choose the first option (the "try ubuntu" thing) and then this happen. http://cdn5.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/650x300xubuntu-boot-error.jpg.pagespeed.ic.VZB6J0B3_b.webp

My computer is in Windows 7, 32-bit. What else I can do?

Comment: Can you try redownload and reburn the ISO? There is a possibility that the ISO was corrupt.

Comment: I can't boot my computer. Can't turn it on. That means I can't burn it to the d drive again. I'm using someone else's computer now

Comment: Does your computer boot to BIOS/UEFI (computer vendor logo)?

Comment: Like, when I boot my computer, it shows the computer logo (like most computers)? Yes I guess.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu alongside windows 7 or make your computer Ubuntu only? Or did it not boot to installer because of kernel oops/panic...

Comment: I haven't install ubuntu. And yes, it does boot to the installer.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Check that you have burned the correct image**
Make sure the image that you downloaded was a x32 image.
**2. Try reinstalling  the image**
I've used [Pen Drive  Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) in the past, but for live USBs. Maybe it will help with some issues, but do some research first. I'm not sure if it will work on hard drives since it is meant for USBs.

Comment: 1. Maybe I really shouldn't read the recommended thing (x64). Fff 2. My USB got corrupted. Anyone knows any website that I can ask about this?

Answer (score -1):

Better re-image  your system, all i can understand is that your system and OS is having compatibility issue.. So check one more time carefully and then install it should work